# Decrypt PGP file using ASC key

Tags: encryption, pgp, decryption

I installed the command line version of pgp and I received a .pgp file and its key in a .asc file.

How can I decrypt the pgp file using command line and the asc key?

Answer (score 23):

For **[GnuPG](http://www.gnupg.org/)**, it's done like this.

Import the key:

```
gpg --import key.asc
```

Decrypt the file:

```
gpg --decrypt file.pgp
```

---

For **[PGP Command Line](http://www.pgp.com/products/commandline/)**, it's mostly the same:

```
pgp --import key.asc
```

```
pgp --decrypt file.pgp
```